# Can't access to mysql via terminal

Tags: mysql, terminal, mamp, root

I'm unable to get access into mysql via terminal. I've installed MAMP on my MacOS High Sierra (10.13.5). 
Apache & MySQL started, but after prompting the command:
*/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot*
nothing happens.
P.S. Path leading to MAMP binaries is correct.

[screen from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtwVt.png)

Unfortunately, I didn't find solution at StOvfl.

Comment: Does it return to the command prompt immediately? What happens if you omit the parameters?

Comment: Yes, it returns answer immediately. Omitting parameters since _--host(..)_ provides the same result.

Comment: Reinstalling MAMP solved the problem.